# Measuring font-size in pixels

Tags: html, css

When specifying font-size like this:

```css
p {
  margin:0;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<p>hello</p>
```

Is it safe to assume that computed `height` of `p` will be the vertical distance from the lowest Descender to the highest Ascender?

[image]

Comment: The image " https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bbSb.png " cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: strange, worked for me. is it OK now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume that computed height of p will be the vertical distance from the lowest descender to the highest ascender?

No

There's no way to know how high or low a typeface will go. While you could certainly design a typeface so that ascenders/descenders fit in the given font-size there's no reason you can't build a typeface that has flourishes that extend significantly below or above the normal range.

Handwriting style fonts often don't even all align on the same baseline.

`font-size` is really more of a suggestion than a rule.

Answer (score -2):

No, the biggest factor is probably going to be `line-height`.

Also bear in mind that some fonts are made better than others. Some fonts sit in different positions vertically and there really seems to be no standard.